# _construct method is not called

Tags: php

I am using Netbeans editor.
I initialize a constructor method in my class

```
class test {
  public $prop= 'i am class property';
  public function _construct(){
    echo 'hello class"', __CLASS__, '" is initiated';
  }

  public function setname($newvar){
    $this->prop=$newvar;

  }
  public function getname(){
    return $this->prop."</br>";

  }

}

$obj = new test ;
echo $obj->getname();
```

My `_construct` method is not working not giving output of class name

Answer (score 1):

Constructor in PHP begins with two underscores, i.e. `__construct`. When you use one underscore, it's just a method and is not called on object's creation.

See [manual for constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should uses 2 underscores: __constructor if you use only one then it's just a method.  Good luck